# How to have separate urls for the same app in Django 1.9

Tags: django

I have an app that will have 2 kinds of urls, one that will be included in other apps and one will be included in the settings app. I want to have a way to include only part of the urls without creating a seperate file for it.

```
# records app -- urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/$', RecordCreate.as_view(), name="record-create"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', RecordUpdate.as_view(), name="record-update"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', RecordDelete.as_view(), name="record-delete"),
]


urlpatterns_types = [
    url(r'^$', RecordTypeList.as_view(), name="record-type-list"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', RecordTypeDetail.as_view(), name="record-type-detail"),
    url(r'^create/$', RecordTypeCreate.as_view(), name="record-type-create"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', RecordTypeUpdate.as_view(), name="record-type-update"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', RecordTypeDelete.as_view(), name="record-type-delete"),
]
```

Now in the settings app I want to include only the `urlpatterns_types` urls. However I tried to include them but I couldn't

The only way that I found to create separate files and then include them as a module

Here is an example of the expected result

```
# player app -- urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [

    # Records App Urls
    url(r'^(?P<player_id>\d+)/records/', include('records.urls')),
]



# settings app -- urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [

    # Records App Urls
    url(r'^(?P<player_id>\d+)/records/', include('records.urls.urlpatterns_types')),
]
```

---

Project Tree

```
-- soccer_game
    -- soccer_game
        -- settings.py
        -- urls.py

    -- players
        -- models.py
        -- urls.py
        -- views.py

    -- main_settings
        -- models.py
        -- urls.py
        -- views.py
```

Comment: are these 2 separate django projects with common code?

Comment: @JossefHarush all in the same project three apps `records` `players` and `settings` I want to include the records settings urls in the settings app and the main urls to the players app

Comment: do you have `urls.py` per project? can you add a screen shot of your directory tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import the module and pass the list of urls itself:

```
# settings app -- urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from records import urls as records_urls
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    # Records App Urls
    url(r'^(?P<player_id>\d+)/records/', include(records_urls.urlpatterns_types)),
]
```